# Make a R2 graph with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, coefficient-of-determination

I have datas in two lists. One with the real ones (observed) and one with the predicted ones.

I wanna put it in a graph to get something with the two lists with different colors and the line between them but I don't get how to put the line in the graph even after all my researches.

[Here is what I want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqt0W.png)

For now, here's my code that shows the two lists. I don't get where to place my r_squared variable.

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

observed = [1, 4, 9]
predicted = [1.2, 4.1, 8.7]

r_squared = r2_score(observed, predicted)

plt.plot(observed, 'o', predicted, 'o')
```

Answer (score 1):

The R^2 value is the coefficient of determination and it tells you how well your predicted values match the observed values, see [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/bivariate-data-ap/assessing-fit-least-squares-regression/a/r-squared-intuition) for more info. There isn't anywhere to really place your r_squared variable besides printing it or displaying the value on the graph.

The line you see in the example graph represents an R^2 value of 1, i.e where the predicted values perfectly match the observations.

To draw this line you could just do

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

observed = [1, 4, 9]
predicted = [1.2, 4.1, 8.7]

r_squared = r2_score(observed, predicted)

plt.plot(observed, predicted, 'o')

x = range(10)
y = range(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

print(r_squared)
```